# condition of .length before adding a Class Jquery

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have this code who work pretty well , just need to add a class when theres no checkbox checked. Actually i just add a class when checked but i also need to assign a class  when thares no checkboxes checked . So at begining div should grey, then if one or more checkboxes are checked addclass green, then if all checkboxes are unchecked assign red class ;

Here is code : http://jsfiddle.net/hZeyd/10/

```
$(".quest").show();
var $anrs = $(".ans").hide();

$('.quest').click(function(){
    var $ans = $(this).next().toggle(10);
    $anrs.not($ans).hide();
});

$('.ans').change(function(){
    var $ans = $(this).closest('.ans');
    $ans.prev().toggleClass('question-active', $ans.find('input:checkbox:checked').length > 0)
});
```

thanks for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just toggle the `red` class, `true` when no checkboxes are checked, and `false` otherwise:

```
$ans.prev()
  .toggleClass('question-active', $ans.find('input:checkbox:checked').length > 0)
  .toggleClass('red', $ans.find('input:checkbox:checked').length == 0);
```

#### [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hZeyd/11/)